# how to add two numbers with this python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

//Function prototype:

int solveMeFirst(int a, int b);

where,

a is the first integer input.
b is the second integer input
Return values

sum of the above two integers//

```
def solveMeFirst(a,b):

   return a+b

 num1 = int(input(2))
 num2 = int(input(3))
 res = solveMeFirst(num1,num2)
 print(res)
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: `input(2)` is asking the user for `input`, `2` isn't doing anything, besides being display in the input prompt. Try: `solveMeFirst(2,3)` and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem in input(). Which takes user input.

```
def solveMeFirst(a,b):

   return a+b

num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
res = solveMeFirst(num1,num2)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to add two numbers in python.
First----

```
num1=int(input("Enter first number"))
num2=int(input("Enter second number"))
num3=num1+num3
print(num3)
```

Second---Using Functiion--

```
def AddNumbers(num1,num2):
    return num1+num2
num1=int(input("Enter first number"))
num2=int(input("Enter second number"))
num3=AddNumbers(num1,num2)
print(num3)
```

Third ---Using Class--

```
class ADD:
    def __init__(self,num1,num2):
          self.num1=num1
          self.num2=num2
    def addNum(self):
          return self.num1+self.num2
obj1=ADD(2,4)
print(obj1.addNum)
```

Didn't mind if there is any spelling mistake in code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is that you're requesting a user input yet have put your own numbers into that input. An easy fix is to replace

```
num1 = int(input(2))
num2 = int(input(3))
```

with

```
num1 = int(input("Enter your first number"))
num2 = int(input("Enter your second number:"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try with this example based on the code:

```
def solveSimpCalc(x, y):
     return x+y`

FirstNum = int(input("Please type the first number:"))
SecondNum = int(input("Please type the second number:"))
result = solveSimpCalc(FirstNum, SecondNum)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to ***define*** a function(I have used here ***add_numbers***). Then take two parameters(Here is **x** and **y**). Now you can take input from the user. Use the **sum** function to add the number and print it.  The example is below:

```
def add_number(x,y):
    return sum
x = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
y = int(input("Enter the second number: ")) 
sum = x+y
print("The sum is: ", sum)
```

Comment: Problem in the question was with getting the numbers as inputs, and not the calculation function.

Answer (score 0):

```
def solveMeFirst(a,b):

   return a+b

num1 = int(input(2))
num2 = int(input(3))
res = solveMeFirst(num1,num2)
print(res)
```

or you count remove the function to optimise the code.

```
num1 = int(input(2))
num2 = int(input(3))
res = num1+num2
print(res)
```